# Is it allowed to use the same DetachedCriteria within one Criteria multiple times?

Tags: java, hibernate, criteria

I am just wondering if it is allowed in Hibernate to use the same DetachedCriteria object within one Criteria multiple times. Imagine the following case:

```
DetachedCriteria dCriteria = DetachedCriteria.forClass(A.class)
  .add(Restrictions.eq("id", 1))
  .setProjection(Projections.property("id"));

Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(B.class)
  .add(
    Restrictions.or(
      Restrictions.and(
        Subqueries.exists(dCriteria),
        Restrictions.eq("id", 1)
      ),
      Restrictions.and(
        Subqueries.notExists(dCriteria),
        Restrictions.eq("id", 2)
      )
  )
  .setProjection(Projections.property("id"));
```

Is the usage of dCriteria twice within the this criteria allowed? It seems to work but i am not sure if it might lead to problems in more complex cases (maybe the DetachedCriteria saves same state information during query generation?). I already did some reasearches but i couldn't find an explicit answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No it isn't (always) safe to re-use `DetachedCriteria`. For example: get a list and a rowcount, reusing the `DetachedCriteria`:

```java
DetachedCriteria dc = DetachedCriteria.forClass(A.class);
Criteria c1 = dc.getExecutableCriteria(session);
c1.setProjection(Projections.rowCount());
long count = ((Number) c1.uniqueResult()).longValue();
System.out.println(count + " result(s) found:");

Criteria c2 = dc.getExecutableCriteria(session);
System.out.println(c2.list());
```

This prints:

```
Hibernate: select count(*) as y0_ from A this_
4 result(s) found:
Hibernate: select count(*) as y0_ from A this_ <-- whoops
[4] <-- whoops again
```

Really simple things that don't alter the `DetachedCriteria` *might* be safe, but in general wrap the generation in some kind of factory and re-generate them each time you need them.

Officially, cloning `DetachedCriteria` on each call to `getExecutableCriteria` will never happen. See their [issues](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-1046?jql=text%20~%20%22DetachedCriteria%20clone%22), particularly [HHH-635](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-635) and [HHH-1046](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-1046) where Brett Meyer states: "*The Criteria API is considered deprecated*", and the [developers guide (v4.3 §12)](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/devguide/en-US/html/ch12.html) which states:

> Hibernate offers an older, legacy `org.hibernate.Criteria` API which should be considered deprecated. No feature development will target those APIs. Eventually, Hibernate-specific criteria features will be ported as extensions to the JPA `javax.persistence.criteria.CriteriaQuery`.

**EDIT:** In your example you re-use the same DetachedCriteria inside the same query. The same caveats therefore apply - if you, for instance, use `setProjection` with one of the uses, things go wrong with the second use. For example:

```
DetachedCriteria dCriteria = DetachedCriteria.forClass(A.class)
          .add(Restrictions.eq("id", 1))
          .setProjection(Projections.property("id"));

Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(B.class)
  .add(
    Restrictions.or(
      Restrictions.and(
        Subqueries.exists(dCriteria
                .add(Restrictions.eq("text", "a1")) // <-- Note extra restriction 
                .setProjection(Projections.property("text"))), // <-- and projection
        Restrictions.eq("idx", 1)
      ),
      Restrictions.and(
        Subqueries.notExists(dCriteria),
        Restrictions.eq("idx", 2)
      )
  ))
  .setProjection(Projections.property("id"));

Object o = criteria.list();
```

This yields the SQL:

```
select this_.idx as y0_ from B this_ 
where (
    (exists 
        (select this_.text as y0_ from A this_ where this_.id=? and this_.text=?) and this_.idx=?) 
    or (not exists 
        (select this_.text as y0_ from A this_ where this_.id=? and this_.text=?) and this_.idx=?))
```

We didn't ask for the `text=?` part of the `not exists`, but we got it due to the re-use of the `DetachedCriteria` <sup>†</sup>

<sup>†</sup> *This leads to bad situations where, if you applied the `.add(Restrictions.eq("text" ...` to both uses of `dCriteria`, it would appear twice in both the `exists` and `not exists` in the SQL*

Comment: I have also found this during my researches. But this is about using the DetachedCriteria in two _different_ criterias. I would like to use it twice in the _same_ criteria. I am not sure (and didn't find anything according to that) if the problems also apply to my case.

Comment: @Werzi2001 - the same logic applies - see my edit. If you alter the `dCriteria` internal state in one of the uses inside the `Criteria`, then it affects the other uses of the same `dCriteria`.